# How to setText and getText in a TextView inside GridView custom layout adapter onClick of a button

Tags: android, gridview

My app has following files

1. main_activity.xml

   - LinearLayout
   - GridView
   - Button
   - /LinearLayout
2. custom.xml

   - TextView1
   - TextView2
3. CustomAdapter.java
4. MainActivity.java

So to perform functions like setText, getText, set animations, etc onClick of **Button** i would like to find the TextView1.

I would want code equivalent to

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

for TextView1 in GridView at specific position.

Comment: It's difficult to help you if you don't post more code. Does each grid element have its own TextView? Or is there just one?

Comment: would this edit make my question clear @mwieczorek

Comment: Actual code,please. XML and Java.